# Discrepancy in static site from browser when viewed from domain vs from IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

When I make any changes on the static html file served by `apache2` on my `aws ubuntu` instance, and when I see the site page from the domain name like `abc.com`, it is not getting reflected or it gets reflected with some delay of a few hours.

but when I visit the same page, with the elastic `IP` associated with that `EC2` instance then I can see the change.

what could be the reason for this?

The File is served on `EC2` instance with `EBS` store.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible cases:

1. After making the html change in apache, and prior to accessing the domain, are you sure you cleared the browser cache?
2. If you have multiple instances and also have load balancer enabled, ensure that you made the changes in the other instances as well. If this is the case, it could be because your domain is pointing to the load balancer and load balancer is servicing a different instance than you made the changes in.
3. I don't think there is an issue with Domain, but you can also double check the TTL value in the domain and reduce it to 10 minutes. But this is something related to domain level (NX) changes. I don't think this can affect your scenario. But you can double check the domain configurations if you think there could be an issue there.